# Laravel - Eloquent Relationship not working One to Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two models with One-to-Many relationship. I want to display data with relationship in blade.

**Products Table**

```
Table name = Products
PrimaryKey = pro_id
ForeignKey = cat_id
```

**Categories Table**

```
Table name = categories
PrimaryKey = cat_id
```

**Products Model Code**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class productsModel extends Model
{
    //code...
    protected $table      = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey = 'pro_id';

    // Every Products Belongs To One Category

    public function category()
    {
        # code...
        return $this->belongsTo('APP\abcModel','cat_id');
    }
}
```

**Categories Model Code**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class categoryModel extends Model
{
    //code...
    protected $table      = 'categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cat_id';

    // One Category Has Many Products

    public function products()
    {
        # code...
        return $this->hasMany('App\productsModel','cat_id','pro_id');
    }
}
```

**Controller Code**

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\productsModel;
class productsController extends Controller
{
    //code...
    public function products($category_id='')
    {
        # code...
        $data["products"] = productsModel::where
                            ('cat_id',$category_id)
                            ->get();        
        $data["categories"] = productsModel::where
                            ('cat_id',$category_id)->first()->category;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

**ERROR:**
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Class 'APP\categoryModel' not found

Comment: First off you need to look up PSR standards for writing your code and how you name your classes

Comment: APP != App. The namespace is not case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that sometimes you have `App`, sometimes `APP`, while PHP is not case sensitive on class names, you might use an operating system (Linux?) that is case sensitive in terms of file names.

I would recommend to have only `App` everywhere, your error message clearly indicates: `APP`.

Comment: Yes, it will working after changing "APP" to "App" in products Model.

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly see in your model files the `namespace` is written as "`namespace App;`"
There you defined the `namespace` for the app folder. So when you are using this model anywhere, you need to write it as you have defined the `namespace`. Therefore "`App\categoryModel`".
Your code should be as follows:

```
public function category()
{
    # code...
    return $this->belongsTo('App\categoryModel','cat_id');
}
```

Also a sincere request, as @alithedeveloper mentioned please follow PSR standards for writing code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(abcModel::class,'cat_id');
}
```

---

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(productsModel::class,'cat_id');
    }
```